# Covariant data structure with numeric types

Tags: scala, generics, types

How do I create a covariant data structure containing numeric data types?

In scala I can create a covariant data structure, with a hierarchy of type parameters:

```
abstract class Car[+T] {
  def value: T
}
class RaceCar extends Car[RacingWheel] {
  def value: RacingWheel = new RacingWheel
}
class NormalCar extends Car[BoringWheel] {
  def value: BoringWheel = new BoringWheel
}

class Wheel
case class RacingWheel() extends Wheel
case class BoringWheel() extends Wheel

object Car {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val rCar: Car[Wheel] = new RaceCar
    val nCar: Car[Wheel] = new NormalCar
    val listCars: List[Car[Wheel]] = List(rCar, nCar)
  }
}
```

However, when I replace the Wheel's with numeric data types I run into a problem, because the numeric data types do not have a common type parent other than AnyVal:

```
abstract class Item[+N] {
  def value: N
}
class IntItem(x : Int) extends Item[Int] {
  override def value: Int = x
}
class DoubleItem(x : Double) extends Item[Double] {
  override def value: Double = x
}

object Item {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // ERROR Expression of IntItem does not conform to expected type Item[Number]
    val iItem: Item[Number] = new IntItem(10)
    // ERROR Expression of DoubleItem does not conform to expected type Item[Number]
    val dItem: Item[Number] = new DoubleItem(10.9)
    val l: List[Item[Number]] = List(iItem, dItem)

    // ERROR: Expression of IntItem does not conform to expected type Item[Double]
    val iItem2: Item[Double] = new IntItem(10)
    val dItem2: Item[Double] = new DoubleItem(10.9)
    val l2: List[Item[Double]] = List(iItem2, dItem2)
  }
}
```

Outside of the covariant data structure I get mixed results:

```
object NumberMain {
  val a : Int = 5
  val b : Double = 10.0
  val list : List[Number] = List(a, b)
  // works, so Number must be related to Int and Double, right?

  val x : Number = 5
  // ERROR: Expression of type Number doesn't conform to expected type Int
  val y : Int = x
  // does not work, so Number is not related to Int and Double after all...
}
```

What changes do I have to make to the Item data structure? Can I tell it that all items can be seen as of type numeric?

Comment: I'm failing to see the logical flow here. Why would you want `Item[Double]` to be covariantly conform to `Item[Int]`? This feels a little like the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: `Int` and `Double` do not share hierarchy in Scala with a common `Number`. Check out the [`Numeric`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html) typeclass to achieve something similar.

Comment: Well this is a MVP. What I really want to do is to create a data structure _Metric_ with a getter _getter_ that returns different numeric values in its children _Counter_ (Long) and _Meter_.(Double). Then I want to create a Container storing a history of these metrics, so that in the end I can compute something along the lines of val x : Map[(String, Container[Metric])] = ...; val res : Map[String, Number] = x.map(_._1 -> _._2.sum)

Comment: I tried to find information on doing something along this lines with Numeric, but I could not find anything relevant. If you have a pointer to any resource in this direction, please let me know :)

Comment: If I have more time later I can attempt to write a proper answer, but here's a quick hint in the meantime - whenever you're dealing with subtyping, you will sooner or later hit the wall you're hitting now, and that is - inability to enforce the subtyping relationship on existing types, such as Int and Double (let's say Number doesn't exist; it won't suit your needs anyway, plus there may be other situations too). When this happens, type classes are the way to go. Instead of saying "a number", say "some T for which implicit MyNumber[T]" exists, and implement MyNumber[Int] and MyNumber[Double].

Comment: I'm going to write the answer so he/she can understand the concept of Typeclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scala, `Int` and `Double` do not share hierarchy with a common `Number` class. The [Typeclass pattern](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html) can help you in these cases to define extra features for types without a common supertype.

```
trait MyNumber[A]

implicit case object IntMyNumber extends MyNumber[Int]
implicit case object DoubleMyNumber extends MyNumber[Double]

class Item[N](x: N)(implicit n: MyNumber[N]) {
  def value: N = x
}
```

The `Item` class constructor now expects a second group of parameters labeled with the `implicit` keyword. If you call the method without this group of parameters, the compiler tries to find it (an instance of `MyNumber`) from variables or imports also labeled with `implicit` ([Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html)).

We're just defining here that `Int` and `Double` implements `MyNumber`, but it doesn't do anything. We can write then the class as:

```
class Item[N : MyNumber](x: N) {
  def value: N = x
}
```

And it works as we expected:

```
val iItem = new Item(1)
val dItem = new Item(1.0)

scala> iItem.value
res1: Int = 1
scala> dItem.value
res2: Double = 1.0
```

If we try to build an item of anything without an instance of `MyNumber`, the compiler throws an error:

```
val sItem = new Item("S")
error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type MyNumber[String]
```

If you want `MyNumber` to be any numeric, Scala implements a `Numeric` typeclass.

**Edit**

If you want to add some features to the typeclass that are different for each number, you can do:

```
trait MyNumber[A] {
    def doStuff(a: A): Unit
}

implicit case object IntMyNumber extends MyNumber[Int] {
    def doStuff(number: Int): Unit = println("Int")
}

implicit case object DoubleMyNumber extends MyNumber[Double] {
    def doStuff(number: Double): Unit = println("Double")
}

case class Item[+N](x: N)(implicit myNumber: MyNumber[N]) {
  def value: N = x
  def doStuff = myNumber.doStuff(x)
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you for taking the time this is great input! One issue that I have with the solution is that it breaks the double hierarchy. With this solution I cannot define custom function for my _DoubleItem_, that is not available for my _IntItem_:
  
class IntItem[X] extends Item[X] {  
  def doStuff() = ???  
}  
class DoubleItem[Y] extends Item[Y] {  
  def doOtherStuff() = ???  
}  

And how do I define the type of a list containing the Item?  
val l : List[Item[???]] = List(Item(10), Item(5.3))

Comment: I updated the answer to do what you want. If you want to store different values in a list, you get to the same problem as before. They still don't share hierarchy, the compiler just knows they both implement MyNumber. I think the best you can do here is to have a `List[Item[AnyVal]]` if you define Item with a covariant type parameter (`Item[+N]`). I'm not 100% sure about this, maybe someone can help us out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I think there are many issues that I still have to get to grips with, but this solves the particular problem.